# Handling Backend Events in UI class

Tags: c#, wpf

EDIT: I have updated this with the two methods recommended

I am writing a simple custom PI ([OSISoft](https://www.osisoft.com/)) data viewer. I have two classes, one for the UI and one for the PI server interactions/program logic. The property for the data to be displayed has an event that fires when the property is changed. How do I get that change to propagate over to the UI class so the associated text box will automatically refresh?

Original code:

```
namespace PIViewer {
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        ProgLogic logic;

        public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();
            logic = new ProgLogic();
            InitializeValues();
        }

        private void InitializeValues() {
            logic.SomeValue = logic.GetValFromServer(valueTag);
        }

        private void TextBoxSomeValue(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e) {
            //  ??? something happens here?
        }
    }

    public class ProgLogic {
        private int someValue;

        public event System.EventHandler SomeValueChanged;

        protected void OnSomeValueChanged()
        {
            SomeValueChanged?.Invoke(this, EventHandlerArgs e);
        }

        public int SomeValue {
            get => someValue;
            set {
                someValue = value;
                OnSomeValueChanged();
            }
        }

        public int GetValFromServer(string valueTag) {
            int piValue;
            piValue = PISDKMethodToGetServerValue(valueTag);
            return piValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Method 1: Events

```
namespace PIViewer {
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        ProgLogic logic;

        public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();
            logic = new ProgLogic();
            logic.SomeValueChanged += Logic_SomeValueChanged;
            InitializeValues();
        }

        private void Logic_SomeValueChanged(int obj) {
            TextBoxSomeValue.Text = obj.toString();
        }

        private void InitializeValues() {
            logic.SomeValue = logic.GetValFromServer(valueTag);
        }

        private void TextBoxSomeValue_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e) {

        }

        private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e) {
            logic.SomeValueChanged -= Logic_SomeValueChanged;
        }

    }

    public class ProgLogic {
        private int someValue;

        public event Action<int> SomeValueChanged;

        public virtual void OnSomeValueChanged(int newValue) {
            SomeValueChanged?.Invoke(newValue);
        }

        public int SomeValue {
            get => someValue;
            set {
                someValue = value;
                OnSomeValueChanged(value);
            }
        }

        public int GetValFromServer(string valueTag) {
            int piValue;
            piValue = PISDKMethodToGetServerValue(valueTag);
            return piValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Method 2: MVVM pattern

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window
    Closing="Window_Closing"
    Title="My App">
    <TextBox x:name="TextBoxSomeValue" text="{binding SomeValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
</Window>
```

The important part here is the *binding* parameter in the text field of the TextBox definition, which points to the PropertyChangedEventHandler.

C# code:

```
namespace PIViewer {
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        ProgLogic logic;

        public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();
            logic = new ProgLogic();
            InitializeValues();
        }

        private void InitializeValues() {
            logic.SomeValue = logic.GetValFromServer(valueTag);
        }

        private void TextBoxSomeValue_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e) {
            //  run some other code when the text box updates
        }
    }

    public class ProgLogic : INotifyPropertyChanged {
        private int someValue;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChange(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public int SomeValue {
            get => someValue;
            set {
                someValue = value;
                OnPropertyChange("SomeValue")
            }
        }

        public int GetValFromServer(string valueTag) {
            int piValue;
            piValue = PISDKMethodToGetServerValue(valueTag);
            return piValue;
        }
    }
}
```

ProgLogic now implements INotifyPropertyChanged, which notifies the View of property changes, so that Bindings are updated.

Comment: Is this WPF or Winforms?

Comment: How is this related to VS2019?

Comment: @Twenty not anymore, I edited the tags, as that specific one was irrelevant.

Comment: @RobertHarvey WPF

Comment: OK.  You should consider adding a third class as a ViewModel for your MainWindow, and use Data Binding to bind your UI controls to properties in your ViewModel class.  Then all you have to do is simply change the property in the ViewModel when you get a new value, and the UI will automatically display the new value.

Comment: See here for more info: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/raj1979/simple-mvvm-pattern-in-wpf/ , https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thanks, will give that a try also!

Comment: Fair warning: it's a bit of a learning curve.  But a ViewModel will always scale better.  Code-behind will only scale for the smallest of applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are heading the right way with C# event system. One thing I would change is event type from `System.EventHandler` to `System.Action<int>`. Even though people tend to propagate extending `System.EventArgs` class and writing custom delegates for handling events, using `System.Action<T>` is much easier to grasp for beginner.

So let's go with `System.Action<int>` example now. First, let's change `ProgLogic` class to be more like this:

```
public class ProgLogic
{
    public event Action<int> SomeValueChanged;

    //
    // your other code goes here
    //

    private void OnSomeValueChanged(int newValue)
    {
        SomeValueChanged?.Invoke(newValue);
    }
}
```

Now, you need to subscribe to the earlier written event in `MainWindow` class. So we do that as early as possible - in the constructor of `MainWindow`:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    logic = new ProgLogic();
    logic.SomeValueChanged += OnSomeValueChanged;
    InitializeValues();
}
```

Then, you describe your logic in the `OnSomeValueChanged` callback method, like:

```
private void OnSomeValueChanged(int newValue)
{
    TextBoxSomeValue.text = newValue.ToString();
}
```

Make sure you unsubscribe from the event once `MainWindow` is getting destroyed to prevent memory leakage. This is just bare-bones for whole logic. I've left some space for interpretation. ;)

Comment: It's been a couple years since I've used C# extensively.  Has best practices shifted from `EventHandler<T>` to `Action<T>` or is that just your preference?

Comment: I never said it's best practice. Quoting my answer 'even though people tend to propagate extending System.EventArgs class and writing custom delegates for handling events, using System.Action<T> is much easier to grasp for beginner'.

Comment: @TomasŠvedas Please see the above edits. VS2019 was smart enough to recognize what I was doing and auto-generated the Logic_SomeValueChanged callback method.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding the main point of your question but if you want to create a new value and have that value saved as the default value then you should create a string in your application setting and call on it on text changed.

1. At the top of your visual2019, in the menu options. open the debug menu and at the bottom you will see ("Your project name" + properties)

2.You will be brought into a new window with menu options on the left, go to the settings.

3.Create a string and set the value to "Some random text"

Note: In the example I placed one text box in front of the other, though this in not a great method it will prevent the text from appearing as a double or drawing a blank

[Settings String Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qy2rC.jpg)

```
    xaml
    <Window x:Class="SaveNewText.MainWindow"                
       Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
        <Grid>
           <TextBox x:Name="DefaultText" Height="250" Width="250" 
           Background="Transparent" 
           Foreground="Black" MouseDown="TextBlock_MouseDown" IsReadOnly="True"/>
           <TextBox x:Name="NewText" Height="250" Width="250" Background="Transparent" 
           Foreground="Black" TextChanged="NewText_TextChanged"/>
        </Grid>
    </Window>

    xaml.cs
    namespace SaveNewText
    {   
      public partial class MainWindow : Window
      {
         public MainWindow()
         {
            InitializeComponent();
            DefaultText.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.TextString;
         }
         private void TextBlock_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
         {
           NewText.Focus();
         } 
         private void NewText_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
         {
             Properties.Settings.Default.TextString = NewText.Text;
             Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
             DefaultText.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.TextString;
         }
     }
   }
```